# Sex Ratio at birth simulation in R

Tags: r

**My problem:**

If the sex ratio at birth (male to female) is 1.1, but people adopt the following
strategy: have children until you have one son, and then stop, unless you have 12
daughters (in which case you stop, too). What would be the average sex ratio in the
population? (Calculate by simulation. Suppose you randomly select 10,000 families.)

**My code**

```
  pm=0.5238095 # Probability of Male
  pw=0.4761905 #                Female
  w=0          # initial number of Female
  n=1          # loop
  p=0          # count of number 
  for(i in 1:n){
  s=rbinom(1,1,0.4761905)
  if(s==1){
  w=w+1
  }
   p=p+1
 while(w<=12){ ####1. How to count the number of female? ###
 while(s==1){
 s=rbinom(1,1,0.4761905)
 if(s==1){
  w=w+1
 }
  p=p+1
 }
 }
  f[i]=p
 }
 w/p
```

**My question**

1. How to count the number of female? I'm using loop to count the number of women$(if(s==1){
     w=w+1
    }). $It seems inefficient.I think MAYBE counting true or false is more efficient.
2. How to write the code more concise?

Comment: maybe you can explain what are `pm`, `pw`, `w`, `n`, `p`, `s` and `f`? in your final loop, you're subsetting `f` but `f` is not defined prior to that, doesn't it give you an error message?

Comment: @plannapus  It runs without end, so I cannot post error message :)

Comment: What is the point of defining the probabilities at the top if you just hard code them in later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, of course, is that this strategy won't affect the sex ratio at all! At least as you've set this up, no matter what a couple's previous birth history is, the probability of a male arising from each birth is always the same.

Here's one way to confirm that with some calculations. (The code's offered without further explanation, at least for now.):

```
pm <- 0.5238095
m <- cbind(boys=c(rep(1, 12), 0), girls=0:12)
p <- c(dgeom(0:11, pm), 1-pgeom(11, pm))

## Calculate expected number of boys and girls for an immortal couple pursuing
## this "strategy"
(res <- p %*% m)
#           boys     girls
# [1,] 0.9998641 0.9089674
p[1] / sum(p)
# [1] 0.5238095   ## Look familiar
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is very inefficient.  Perhaps I can address just a couple of things that almost make sense and it will give you your answer.  In your code...

```
 for(i in 1:n){
    s=rbinom(1,1,0.4761905)
    if(s==1){
    w=w+1
 }
```

can be rewritten as...

```
 s = rbinom(n,1,0.4761905)     
 w = sum(s)
```

That's the same result.  Keep in mind that rbinom is producing 0's and 1's.  You can just sum them to know how many 1's.  Given that you define n then the number of 0s (females) is...

```
 n - w
```

But, if you didn't it would be easy to find too...

```
length(s) - sum(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is still probably inefficient but at least it's correct for what you're trying to do:

```
# set.seed(1)
pw <- 0.4761905 # Initial sex ratio
w <- 0 # number of daughters
n <- 10000 # number of families
p <- 0 # number of kids 
f <- data.frame(Daughters=vector(length=n), Kids=vector(length=n))
for(i in 1:n){
    while(w < 12 & w==p){ #As long as you don't have 12 daughters or 1 son...
    s <- rbinom(1,1,pw)
    if(s==1){w <- w+1}
    p <- p+1
    }
f[i,] <- c(w,p) #Number of daughter and total kids in each families
w <- p <- 0 # Reset number of kids and daughters for the next family
}
colSums(f)[1]/colSums(f)[2] #Final sex ratio
Daughters 
0.4736842 # So as @JoshO'Brien pointed out, very close to the original sex ratio.
```

And you can verify vector `f` to see that there is never more than 1 son (number of kids minus number of daughters):

```
range(f[,2]-f[,1])
[1] 1 1 # Range of the number of boys per family
range(f[,1])
[1]  0 11 # Range of the number of daughters per family
nrow(f[f[,1]==0,])
[1] 5275 # Number of families having 1 son and no daughters (to be compared with 1-pw)
```